# Problem with EntityScan Spring anotation. It stops working when moving model classes to new package

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea, spring-data-jpa

This is a strange case, I think. Certainly a fringe problem, but I don't know exactly where it is or if it's a spring problem or an IntelliJ problem or even a user problem.

Here's the story:

I have a spring boot app that uses spring data and works just fine.

Running this configuration, it runs great on IntelliJ:

```
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"com.legosoft.disperser.event.model"})
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.legosoft.disperser.event.bean"})
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.legosoft.disperser.event.bean.repositories")
```

One of the repositories I use is this one, and again, with the above configuration everything is ok:

```
package com.legosoft.disperser.event.bean.repositories;

import com.legosoft.disperser.event.model.FileConfiguration;
import com.legosoft.disperser.event.model.FileConfigurationId;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;


public interface FileConfigurationDao extends JpaRepository<FileConfiguration, FileConfigurationId> {
}
```

We needed to rename certain elements of the application, among other things, the packages and modules. So today I get into the office thinking that it'd be at most a couple hours worth of work and that only because there's a lot of documentation to write, thinking that the IDE's refactor -> rename option would actually do the heavy lifting for me.

So, I renamed the model package using the afore mentioned option to

```
com.legosoft.fileengine.core.model
```

which left my Application config like so:

```
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"com.legosoft.fileengine.core.model"})
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.legosoft.disperser.event.bean"})
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.legosoft.disperser.event.bean.repositories")
```

and the previously shown repository changed its imports accordingly:

```
package com.legosoft.disperser.event.bean.repositories;

import com.legosoft.fileengine.core.model.FileConfiguration;
import com.legosoft.fileengine.core.model.FileConfigurationId;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;


public interface FileConfigurationDao extends JpaRepository<FileConfiguration, FileConfigurationId> {
}
```

At first glance, everything was ok, it was just a package change. Everything compiled fine, but upon trying to run the application I got:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.legosoft.fileengine.core.model.FileConfiguration
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetamodelImpl.managedType(MetamodelImpl.java:552)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.<init>(JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.java:74)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaEntityInformationSupport.getEntityInformation(JpaEntityInformationSupport.java:66)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getEntityInformation(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:201)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:151)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:134)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:65)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:305)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:297)
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:211)
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:94)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:300)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:121)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1837)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1774)
    ... 42 common frames omitted
```

Now, here's the part I don't understand. Debugging into the dependencies I found this bit of code that produces the exception in the org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.JpaMetamodelEntityInformation class:

```
public <X> ManagedType<X> managedType(Class<X> cls) {
        ManagedType<?> type = (ManagedType)this.jpaEntityTypeMap.get(cls);
        if (type == null) {
            type = (ManagedType)this.jpaMappedSuperclassTypeMap.get(cls);
        }

        if (type == null) {
            type = (ManagedType)this.jpaEmbeddableTypeMap.get(cls);
        }

        if (type == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Not a managed type: " + cls);
        } else {
            return type;
        }
```

Where from my debugging I've determined that the class it looks for is correct (it gets the class object in its new package) but it seems the entity scanning stops working because all maps used to look for the class in the entity model are empty (jpaEntityTypeMap, jpaMappedSuperclassTypeMap or jpaEmbeddableTypeMap) and literally the only thing that's changed is that the classes changed package.

Now, I don't know if its a problem inherent to the refactor->rename option in IntelliJ since there appears to be nothing obviously wrong (the project compiles, the references are correctly updated) but clearly something strange happened because there's no actual scanning going on, or perhaps I'm not using the tool correctly or maybe there's actually something I've done incorrectly with Spring.

I know the problem is a product of this refactor, because as soon as I revert it the project goes back to working fine, repositories and all. Does anybody know if the problem is IntelliJ, something I haven't yet seen on the Spring side of things or something I'm doing wrong to work the refactor maybe?

Any details that clear up this mess would be greatly appreciated. It's had me grumbling all day and for something that seemed so simple!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is FileConfiguration still marked as a @Entity ?

Comment: Yes, the entity configuration did not change. Only the class package changed. In fact, if I copy the classes themselves manually into a new package and direct the entity scanning to this new package, it works fine. It only breaks if I tell IntelliJ to run refactor -> rename on the package.

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem. Even if you mark "refactor all places" on the refactor -> rename dialog, the package name in entitymanager.packagesToScan in application.properties was not changing.

Since the package path in the annotation in the config application class WAS changing, it never crossed my mind to check the properties file.